# Clearing radio buttons with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need to clear (no selection) my first 2 radio buttons (CMR conv + Out of CMR) when choice is **'Disable things'**.

Is it possible with knockout?

I already disable them but I also need to clear them.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/

```
CMR convention: <input type="radio" name="cmrConvention" value="true" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: cmrConvention, disable: thirdPartyInsured() ? true : false">
<br/>
Out of CMR convention: <input type="radio" name="cmrConvention" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: cmrConvention, disable: thirdPartyInsured() ? true : false">
<br/>
- - - - - -
<br/>
Enable things: <input type="radio" name="thirdParty" value="false" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: thirdPartyInsured">
<br/>
Disable things: <input type="radio" name="thirdParty" value="true" data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: thirdPartyInsured">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the click binding when the "disable things" checkbox is clicked, like so:

```
Disable things: 
<input type="radio" name="thirdParty" value="true" 
       data-bind="checkedRadioToBool: thirdPartyInsured, 
                  click: function() { cmrConvention(null); return true; }">
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/4/).

Comment: You are right: the radio are cleared but the side effect: the 'Disable things' clicked is no more selected. Any idea?

Comment: yup :-) the anonymous function did not return anything, which stopped the "click" event from propagating, and as such, from being checked. You have to return something for it to propagate. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnucj/4/

Comment: You could use `click: cmrConvention.bind($data, null)`